# GIT - how I could count all lines in all files?

Tags: git

I would like count all code lines in all files in current HEAD. How I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to count all lines, or all changed lines? If it's the first one, [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) will count LOC for you.